# How can I keep running a for loop if Observable doesn't return the correct response.

Tags: angular, google-maps-api-3, firebase, ionic2, observable

Im using the Google maps API to let a user search for a city and then I query my Firebase database based on the addressType. The google response returns different addressTypes (locality, add_level_1, add_level_2, ...), and I want to be able to execute different queries if I don't get a result.

**How my project should work:** I get the object of the Google API, then based on that information I search for POI, first based on 'locality', if that doesn't return a result (no objects found in firebase) I execute the same query but based on 'adm_level_2', and so on.

**What I've got so far:** I'm able to get the Google API response and then execute the query to find POI based on 'locality', and show that response in my app. But I can't figure out how to execute a second (and third) query if the first query doesn't return a result.

**My code so far:**

```
 var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        administrative_area_level_2: 'long_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    this.addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[this.addressType]) {
      if (this.addressType == "locality") {
        this.locality = place.address_components[i][componentForm[this.addressType]];
         let rsltBusiness = [];
         self._dataService.getCompaniesForLocationObs(this.addressType,this.locality)
          .map(i=>{return i})
          .subscribe(i => self.staticData =i
          );
      }
      if (this.addressType == "administrative_area_level_2") {
        console.log("adm_level_2 ");
        this.adm_level2 = place.address_components[i][componentForm[this.addressType]];
      } if (this.addressType == "administrative_area_level_1") {
        this.adm_level1 = place.address_components[i][componentForm[this.addressType]];
      }
    }
  }
```

So the first part that works is in the **' if (this.addressType == "locality")'** but if that doesn't return a result I should be able to execute the same query but then from **'if (this.addressType == "administrative_area_level_2") {'**

Is that possible? And if yes, how should I handle that? Or am I trying to do something that is against the proper use of Observables and Angular2 / Firebase?

I don't have a lot of experience with Angular2 so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is gonna work out of the box, since I can't test the code, but I'll try to explain the principal, you implement it:

```
// create a list of types you want to check against from API response

  let addressTypes = [];
  let addressLocality = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    let type = place.address_components[i].types[0]
    addressTypes.push( type );
    addressLocality[ type ] = place.address_components[i][componentForm[type]]
  }

// Search database for each 'addressType' you found.
   Observable.from(addressTypes)
     .mergeMap(type => self._dataService
       .getCompaniesForLocationObs(type, addressLocality[type]))

// Assuming 'getCompaniesForLocationObs()' returns false if it doesn't find anything
      .filter(Boolean)

// If something is found stop 
       .take(1)

// Execute!
       .subscribe(i => self.staticData = i)
```

Remember, observable evaluates whole chain of operators you set up for each source item before evaluating next one. So you just need to create a list of things you want to query from API response (my for-loop will probably not work) and let observable do it's thing (;

And don't forget imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was lookin for, but unfortunately I still can't seem to show the correct response. I think it might have something to do with how I get my Firebase response?

Comment: dank, pressed enter to soon. :) below here is my Firebase query and how I return the data, it would be greatly appreciated if you could have a look and see if maybe i'm doing something wrong there?  getCompaniesForLocationObs(index, location){
      var businessList;
      return businessList = this.af.database.list('/business/' , {
          query: {
          orderByChild: index,
          equalTo: location
        }
      })
    }

Comment: Are you not getting data from FB, or that observable isn't working? Your function returns an empty array (af.db.list() returns empty array if nothing is found), so `.filter(Boolean)` in my code won't work. If that's the issue replace it with `.filter(res => res.length > 0)` or similar. Don't see here anything else that could cause problems...

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what the problem was. I couldn't find any information that af.db.list() returned an empty array. Thank you.